# I am dns forwarding so my lightsail IP address appears like a domain I own from IONOS. Doing this disables mobile scaling? Why?

Tags: reactjs, dns

My website; lets say xx.xxx.xxx.xxx is the dns for some-domain.com.

If I connect to xx.xxx.xxx.xxx with a mobile device, my React app scales appropriately.

If I connect to some-domain.com, it displays it as if on a desktop.

Why is this? Can I fix this easily?

[on ip address](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dmoIh.png)

[using url](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lSA4c.png)

Answer (score 0):

I have done further research and found that the use of frames in HTML is depricated. I have no idea why IONOS still offers frames as a way to mask the ip.

Regardless, the better approach is to use A records.

Curiously, you can do this on IONOS, but they do not do it for you. They offer HTTP redirecting but it then shows the ip.

https://www.name.com/support/articles/205188538-pointing-your-domain-to-hosting-with-a-records

anyway, the above guide helped me and the interface is quite similar on IONOS when adding your own A records. The A records IONOS creates are not ideal.